# What is the fld qword[EBP+8] in this quadratic equation code and also what does fadd ST0 do with just one argument?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x87

```
    ; roots.asm
segment ;gcc.text
global -c rootsc._roots

_roots:
        enter   0,0     ;create stack frame for procedure parameters
        xor     EAX,EAX                 ;EAX = 0
        fld     qword[EBP+8]            ; load floating point value : a
        fadd    ST0                     ; 2a
        fld     qword[EBP+8]            ; a,2a
        fld     qword[EBP+24]           ; c,a,2a
;nasm        fmulp   ST1                     ; ac,2a
        fadd    ST0                     ; 2ac,2a
        fadd    st0                     ; 4ac,2a
        fchs                            ; -f4ac,2a
 elf64       fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,-g4ac,2a
        fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,b,-F4ac,2a
 stabs       fmulp   ST1                     ; b*b,-o4ac,2a
 roots.o roots.asm      faddp   ST1                     ; b*b-4ac,2a
;gcc rootsc.o       ftst                            ; cmp (b*b-4ac),0
        fstsw   AX                      ; result of test in AX
        sahf                            ; store AH in flag reg
        jb      no_real_roots           ; jb tests the carry flag
        fsqrt                           ; sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fchs                            ; -b,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fadd    ST1                     ; -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac),sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fdiv    ST2                     ; -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        mov     EAX,dword[EBP+32]       ; EAX = -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        fstp    qword[EAX]              ; Store and pop
        fchs                            ; -sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fchs                            ; -b,-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        faddp   ST1                     ; -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fdivrp  ST1                     ; -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        mov     EAX,dword[EBP+36]       ; EAX = -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        fstp    qword[EAX]              ; Store and pop
        mov     EAX,1                   ; 1 means real roots.o
        jmp     short done
no_real_roots:
        fchs                            ; Make b*b-o4ac positive
        fsqrt                           ; sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fchs                            ; -b,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fadd    ST1                     ; -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac),sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fdiv    ST2                     ; -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a,sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        mov     EAX,dword[EBP+32]       ; EAX = -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        fstp    qword[EAX]              ; Store and pop
        fchs                            ; -sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fld     qword[EBP+16]           ; b,-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fchs                            ; -b,-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        faddp   ST1                     ; -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac),2a
        fdivrp  ST1                     ; -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        mov     EAX,dword[EBP+36]       ; EAX = -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
        fstp    qword[EAX]              ; Store and pop
        sub     EAX,EAX                 ; 0 means no real roots
done:
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html covers the basics of what x87 instructions do, and the register stack.

Comment: There appear to be fragments of `nasm -felf64` and gcc commands sprinkled into your code, like `-c roots` in the middle of a `global _roots` directive.  So this is a total mess and wouldn't actually assemble without some editing.  (And it will crash if you build it as 64-bit, this uses 32-bit EBP so use `nasm -felf` / `gcc -m32`).  And BTW, it looks inefficient: `fchs` / `faddp` should be `fsubrp st1` (reverse-subtract instead of changing sign and adding.)  And instead of loading from memory twice, you can `fld st0` to duplicate the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
fld     qword[EBP+8]            ; load floating point value : a
```

Reads the `double` value from the address given (in the stack frame) and pushes it into register `ST0` on the coprocessor stack, moving all other registers along one.

I have not seen this syntax before, with a single register

```
fadd    ST0                     ; 2a
```

but it implies the use of `ST` as the other operand and destination register. In this case it adds `ST0` to itself.

Please observe the comments, which list the coprocessor register contents `ST0`, `ST1`... etc. The registers form a stack so the next instruction in sequence

```
fld     qword[EBP+8]            ; a,2a
```

pushes another copy of the same value onto the register stack, moving other register contents along one, as shown by the comment.

Comment: Thankyou, just one last question what is qword used for

Comment: It indicates that the operand is of size 8 bytes. The data can be 4 (`DWORD`), 8 (`QWORD`) or 10 (`TBYTE`) bytes, for `float`, `double` and `long double` C types.